# How to limit graph to only show points above the positive x axis?

Tags: r, plot, xts

I currently have a plot of my data that looks like this:

[image: plot of my data]

However because of the negative spike in around 2017, the graph shows values above and below the x axis. How do I make it so the graph only shows values above the x axis?

This is the code I am currently using to produce my graph

`plot(dandpw)
addLegend(lty = 1)`

mydata
`> head(dandpw)
                    QLD1.Price NSW1.Price VIC1.Price SA1.Price TAS1.Price
2008-01-07 10:30:00   33.81019   36.52777   49.66935 216.45379   30.88968
2008-01-14 10:30:00   45.09321   37.55887   49.04155 248.33518   51.16057
2008-01-21 10:30:00   27.22551   29.57798   31.28935  31.56158   45.99226
2008-01-28 10:30:00   26.14283   27.32113   30.20470  31.90042   53.48170
2008-02-04 10:30:00   91.86961   36.77000   37.09027  37.57167   56.28464
2008-02-11 10:30:00   62.60607   28.83509   34.95866  35.18217   55.78961`

[dput(head(dandpw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cu6H.png)

Comment: Can you include the output from `dput(head(dandpw))` instead? Easier for us to paste into R

Comment: > dput(head(dandpw))
structure(c(33.8101941747573, 45.0932142857143, 27.225505952381, 
26.1428273809524, 91.8696130952381, 62.6060714285714, 36.5277669902913, 
37.558869047619, 29.5779761904762, 27.321130952381, 36.77, 28.8350892857143, 
49.6693527508091, 49.0415476190476, 31.2893452380952, 30.2047023809524, 
37.0902678571429, 34.9586607142857, 216.453786407767, 248.335178571429, 
31.5615773809524, 31.9004166666667, 37.5716666666667, 35.1821726190476, 
30.8896763754045, 51.1605654761905, 45.9922619047619, 53.4816964285714, 
56.2846428571429, 55.7896130952381),

Comment: Comments aren't the easiest way to read dput and it looks like some of your output is being chopped off. Could you edit your question to include the dput output?

Comment: Yep, also what does dput mean

Comment: Type “?dput()” in R & hit enter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways. Since there is no usable `dput` (only the picture), I assume your data is in a data frame.

1. You can remove negative numbers from your dataset
2. You can put limits on the y-axis shown in the chart (using `ggplot2`)

Method 1 (not recommended as it alters your data):

```
#remove negatives and replace with NA. Can also replace with 0 if desired
dandpw[dandpw < 0] <- NA
```

Method 2:

```
#assume dandpw is data frame
library(tidyverse)
names(dandpw)[1] <- "date" #looks like your date column might not be named
#ggplot prefers long format
dandpw <- dandpw %>% gather(variables, values, -date)
ggplot(data = dandpw, aes(x = date, y = values, color = variables)) +
 geom_line() + 
 coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, max(dandpw$values, na.rm = T) * 1.1 ))
```